# Unirest for Java

Tags: java, python, unirest

I have a Python Script, which post data to a server url as below.
I want to achieve this using unirest for Java. How do I add parameter/header values for a unirest post request in Java

Python Script:

```
url = 'http://??????????????????/SaveTimeSeriesData'
        params = {'clientId': 'admin', 'tenantId': '075841cb-d7fa-4890-84ea-fdd7d7c65b65', 'destinationId': 'TimeSeries','content-type': 'application/json','content':json.dumps(HTLT_DATA.__dict__)}
      try:
            response= requests.post(url, params=params, proxies=proxies)
            print response 
        except Exception as x:
            print x
```

---

The server endpoint code is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/SaveTimeSeriesData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveMachineData(
        @RequestHeader(value = "authorization", required = false) String authorization,
        @RequestParam("clientId") String clientId, @RequestParam("tenantId") String tenantId,
        @RequestParam("content") String content)
{
```

---

What will be the unirest code in java? Will the below code achieve the same result as the python script

```
    Unirest.post("http://???????????????/SaveTimeSeriesData")
        .field("content", mo)
        .field("tenantId", "075841cb-d7fa-4890-84ea-fdd7d7c65b65")
        .field("clientID","admin")
        .field("content-type","application/json")                   
            .asJson();
```

Comment: Please be specific what is the error it is giving you. Is there an error message

Answer (score 1):

Without any more information I believe it is a simple bug with the location of your quotes.

```
      .field("tenantId, "075841cb-d7fa-4890-84ea-fdd7d7c65b65")
```

should really be

```
      .field("tenantId", "075841cb-d7fa-4890-84ea-fdd7d7c65b65")
```

note that tenant Id had no end quote. The whole line may have been treated as a string literal. Let me know if this fixed the bug

Comment: The quotes was indeed missing..Thanks for pointing out. But my question is will this work as the script

Comment: I do not know. Try to compile it, and see if it works.

Comment: @sromit let me know if this fixed your problem,

Comment: The code compiled fine, but there are other problem in the server side, once that gets fixed, I will let you know, if my unirest code worked or not

Comment: The unirest code is not working..but if I replace with the below code (though for a diff method) works just fine  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    final String uri ="http://?????????????/ping";       
       HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);    
       ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
       System.out.println(result);

Comment: If you solved your own problem try answering it yourself... This is encouraged...